# Auto import declarations in Visual Studio Code for custom npm packages

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have created some npm packages that are hosted on a private npm server and I can use these successfully in my angular projects. However I do not know how to get Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code to automatically find the paths to these packages using 'Ctrl .' (or by hovering with the mouse) in the normal way, so that I can select and generate the import statement.

I am guessing there is more that needs to be done to the package but I cannot find anything online